# Конфигурация nginx для работы с Gitlab

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Имеется Gitlab EE (8.15 omnibus). В документации и репозитории имеются примеры конфигов nginx для работы с Gitlab ([документация](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block), [репо](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf))

Приведу второй пример, как более короткий:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
    server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket;
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name git.mydomain.ru;
    server_tokens off;
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab.error.log;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        gzip off;
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
    }
}
```

nginx нельзя перезапустить ни с первым, ни со вторым. тест конфига дает результат:

```
 $ sudo nginx -t
 nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf:6
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Как настроить nginx для работы с Gitlab?

Comment: git – мимо, а администрирование — слишком широкая метка (мета-метка).

Comment: Нужен фрагмент конфига, в который этот конфиг инклюдится. А точнее, знать, внутри каких блоков делается инклюд. "Как есть" конфиг действительно невалидный, но если его инклюдить внутри блока `http` (что, полагаю, делается по умолчанию), то нормально. Посмотрите в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` ...это я к тому, что результаты вашего теста, скорее всего, не имеют никакого отношения к наблюдаемой проблеме.

Comment: @D-side я так и написал, что результаты теста не показатель. он инклюдится в глобальный. мне бы по проблеме советы получить, почему конфиги в доках не подходят?

Comment: Какая-то же ошибка возникает. Просто не та, что в вопросе. Протестируйте главный конфиг, добавив ваш конфиг гитлаба.

Comment: @D-side как это сделать?

Comment: @while1pass ну, так же как вы тестировали отдельный файл, но указав путь к главному конфигу.

Comment: @D-side nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf:6

Comment: Вот это уже похоже на проблему. Замените в вопросе.

Comment: @D-side прям ошибку заголовком вопроса делать?

Comment: Как минимум замените раздел о тесте, т. к. он вообще не про это.

Comment: Во-певрвых, у вас пропущена `;` после `server_name`. Во-вторых, у вас уже есть конфиг с `default_server`, обычно это `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я директиву listen уже поменял, там новые ошибки пошли, разберусь, напишу ответ

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашелся в документации, нужно было внимательней читать.

В моим случае я использовал nginx уже установленный в системе, [раздел документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation) для этого случая приводит следующий [конфиг](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block):

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name git.example.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$ {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/builds/download {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /ci/api/v1/builds/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  location @gitlab-workhorse {

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    # Do not buffer Git HTTP responses
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;

    ## The following settings only work with NGINX 1.7.11 or newer
    #
    ## Pass chunked request bodies to gitlab-workhorse as-is
    # proxy_request_buffering off;
    # proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

Директивы `passenger_*` могут быть непонятны nginx, при запуске он выдаст ошибку, а при тесте подобное сообщение

```html
$ sudo nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
```

Необходимо [установить Passenger и включить passenger nginx module](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/jessie/#step-2:-enable-the-passenger-nginx-module-and-restart-nginx) (ниже кратко приведу команды, описание можно найти по ссылке выше).

Установка passenger:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Add our APT repository
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update

# Install Passenger + Nginx
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

Влючение passenger-модуля в конфиге nginx

```
include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
```

и перезапуск последнего:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

GitLab запускается и предлагает ввести пароль root-пользователя. Остается тонкая настройка.